# I use devstack to install openstack on ubuntu 14.04, but getting some errors

Tags: openstack, devstack

```
2017-07-25 12:49:25.301 |   File "/opt/stack/neutron/neutron/agent/linux/ip_lib.py", line 31, in <module>
2017-07-25 12:49:25.304 |     from neutron.agent.common import utils
2017-07-25 12:49:25.305 |   File "/opt/stack/neutron/neutron/agent/common/utils.py", line 23, in <module>
2017-07-25 12:49:25.306 |     from neutron.common import utils as neutron_utils
2017-07-25 12:49:25.307 |   File "/opt/stack/neutron/neutron/common/utils.py", line 53, in <module>
2017-07-25 12:49:25.308 |     from neutron.db import api as db_api
2017-07-25 12:49:25.308 |   File "/opt/stack/neutron/neutron/db/api.py", line 21, in <module>
2017-07-25 12:49:25.310 |     from neutron_lib.db import api
2017-07-25 12:49:25.311 | ImportError: cannot import name api
2017-07-25 12:49:25.382 | + lib/neutron-legacy:_configure_neutron_common:1 :   exit_trap
2017-07-25 12:49:25.388 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:494                 :   local r=1
2017-07-25 12:49:25.394 | ++ ./stack.sh:exit_trap:495                 :   jobs -p
2017-07-25 12:49:25.400 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:495                 :   jobs=
2017-07-25 12:49:25.407 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:498                 :   [[ -n '' ]]
2017-07-25 12:49:25.415 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:504                 :   kill_spinner
2017-07-25 12:49:25.422 | + ./stack.sh:kill_spinner:390              :   '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2017-07-25 12:49:25.430 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:506                 :   [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2017-07-25 12:49:25.439 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:507                 :   echo 'Error on exit'
2017-07-25 12:49:25.440 | Error on exit
2017-07-25 12:49:25.446 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:508                 :   generate-subunit 1500986072 893 fail
2017-07-25 12:49:26.417 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:509                 :   [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2017-07-25 12:49:26.431 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                 :   /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2017-07-25 12:49:27.239 | + ./stack.sh:exit_trap:518                 :   exit 1
stack@day-virtual-machine:~/devstack$ devstack
```

Comment: It's worth noting that questions that feature just logs or code, with no explanation, are seen as distinctly low-effort here. Would you expand this with some introductory material as to what your project is, what code you're using, or whatever other detail would set out some helpful context?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the Python dependencies are not being installed by stack.sh.  The devstack install creates a virtual python environment on your server and is supposed to install all of the dependencies.  For some reason you appear to be missing neutron_lib.

Running the following command below should include a package named neutron_lib as available.  If not, then you need to fix you pip configuration or you networking / dns.  All depending on what error message you are seeing.
`pip search neutron_lib`

Do you see any error messages earlier in the log file about pip install failing?

Posting a link to the entire log file would help provide additional insight.